# access hash with hashes

Tags: perl, hash

I have this hash with hashses.

I would like to iterate only the value of '0'.

```
$VAR1 = {
  '1' => {
    '192.168.1.1' => '192.168.1.38'
  },
  '0' => {
    '192.168.32.6' => '192.168.32.43'
  }
};
```

The only way I can access it is by creating two `foreach my $key (keys(%myhash))` loops:

Can I use:

```
foreach my $key (keys(%myhash{0}))  ## does not work
```

or directly access the values somehow?

Thanks

Comment: Have you read [`perlreftut`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlreftut.html) and [`perldsc`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perldsc.html)?

Comment: Could you insert the code for the nested (?) ```foreach``` loops that you used? this would help illustrate and contrast the two different methods of access discussed here: namely that ```5.14``` and up can take a reference directly, while earlier versions require the dereferencing step (and thus the double loop).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, if you are using consecutive integers as keys to a hash then it is likely that you should be using an array instead.

The value of the hash corresponding to key `0` is `$dhcpoffers{0}` because it is a *scalar* value. `%dhcpoffers{0}` is just a syntax error.

You need

```
for my $key (keys %{ $dhcpoffers{0} }) { ... }
```

or, if you prefer

```
my $offer_0 = $dhcpoffers{0};
for my $key (keys %$offer_0) { ... }
```

Since version 14 of Perl 5, `keys` will accept a hash *reference*, so you may be able to write the much cleaner

```
for my $key (keys $dhcpoffers{0}) { ... }
```

Comment: Cool!  Although I have 5.16.3 and can't get ```keys ``` to do what you say.  Can you expand/improves your answer slightly to illustrate?

Comment: @G.Cito: Sorry, there was a typo in my last line of code. Try it now.

Comment: Heh  thanks.  As it turned out I figured it out myself about 5 minutes ago and was going to post a comment :-)  +1 up vote for your quick respose !